# What technology/strategy should I use to render big GeoJSON files within google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gis

I'm currently working on a project to display enriched geographical data within an interactive map. For example, I have housing blocks with additional information added, and I want to display this data within an interactive map. I chose google maps, because I don't have any experience in building a map-based webservice and google seemed to be easy accessible and working.

The problem comes with the amount of information i have. A single town like Berlin has about 450.000 geometrys, which results in a GeoJSON file roughly 170MB big. I know, that this isn't anywhere near to working.

Do you guys can give me a hint on how to structure the project? What kind of technology can I use to dynamically query the needed data? Are there any libraries or working solutions that I should give a try?

Comment: Store your data in a database and query only the information you need, when you need it (for example, only the information that is to be displayed within the current map bounds). By limiting the zoom (out) level or preventing your app from requesting data until a certain zoom level is reached, you also limit the amount of data to be queried/displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved this issue:

I used [mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) to pre-render the tiles and displayed them in google maps using getTileURL. I used [this](http://daynebatten.com/2015/08/google-maps-tiles-mapnik-python/) tutorial, which explains the basics on how to use mapnik for google map tiles.